# How to define a class AND constants in a CommonJS module

Tags: node.js, commonjs

I have seen this thread on how to share constants across CommonJS modules:
[How do you share constants in NodeJS modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595509/how-do-you-share-constants-in-nodejs-modules)

However, if I want the same file to also have a class which should be exposed in the module, then how do I achieve that?

If I do:

> module.exports = class A { ... }

Then I "used" the module.exports object.

Is there a way to mix both class AND constants in the same file?

In es6, I would simple add the term "export" before each one...

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy to figure out. Now, let's say you have a code like this.

```
export class A { }
export const y= 5;
```

Which you basically want. But this is same as

```
class A { }
const x = 5;
exports.A = A;
exports.x = 5;
```

Now, you can figure it out also. open up [babel repl](https://babeljs.io/en/repl) and paste your ES6 code there. It will give you the ES5 equivalent in the right pane.

I pasted that ES6 code and got back

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var A = exports.A = function A() {
  _classCallCheck(this, A);
};

var y = exports.y = 5;
```

Don't worry about `_classCallCheck` it is just a safeguard so that you cannot just call `A()` instead of `new A()`

Comment: I am not looking for an ES6 solution.
I needed one for CommonJS

Answer (score 0):

`module.exports = ...` is a bad practice if there's a chance that a module can have more than one exported value.

There's already existing `module.exports` object that is aliased as `exports`, it's purpose is similar to named exports in ES modules:

```
exports.A = class A { ... };

exports.b = 'constant';
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work.

In file X.js I write:

```
constant B = "value";

class A {

}

modules.exports = {
    A: A,
    B: B  
};
```

In the client code I use:

> const X = require('./X');
>
> let a = new X.A();