# VSCode does not show Code Helper for imports from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-functions

I'm new to Node.JS and VSCode.

I'm coding Firestore Cloud Function.
I want to use a constant file to help me make sure I don't make type-errors.

I have followed the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595509/how-do-you-share-constants-in-nodejs-modules). But the VSCode code helper doesn't show the constants I have defined there.

In `constants.js`:

```
function define(name, value) {
    Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
        value:      value,
        enumerable: true
    });
}

define('kFieldName', 'name');
define('kFieldAge', 'age');
```

Then in `index.js`:

```
var constants = require("./constants");

exports.createUserDocuments = functions
    .runWith({ memory: "128MB", timeoutSeconds: 30 })
    .auth.user().onCreate((user) => {

    // As I type constants.kFieldName here code helper does not show the corresponding definitions

});
```

What I hope to see is as I type the keyword such as `constants.kField` then the Code Helper should show suggestions `kFieldName` and `kFieldAge` just like in Android Studio.

How do I make VSCode's code helper to show the definitions I wrote in `constants.js`?
Is it because I miss something in regards to exports and importing the files?

Thank you!