# how to access constants declared via Object.defineProperty

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am learning how to declare app-wide globla constatnts. referring to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595509/how-do-you-share-constants-in-nodejs-modules)
for the answer of `Dominic Barnes`, for the code titled with `constants.js -- Better`. i copied it and pasted it as  shown in the following lines:

**constants.js**

```
function define(name, value) {
    Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
        value:      value,
        enumerable: true
    });
}

define("PI", 3.14);
```

**invocation to constants.js in app.js**

```
import constants from './constants/constants';
var req=https.get('https://xx/xx/getDistanceFromOriginToDestination/30.976639,30.056021,30.97775,30.033333',options, callback);
constants. //<==========????
req.on('error', (e) => {
    console.error("problem with request:", e);
});
req.end();
```

the propblem is, in the post of the `Dominic Barnes` he can access the `PI` as follows and as shown in his answer:

```
var constants = require("./constants");
console.log(constants.PI); // 3.14
constants.PI = 5;
console.log(constants.PI); // still 3.14
```

in my case, the autocomplete of VS-Codes does not show any thing derived from `constants.js`, or in other words, i can not have access to `PI`.
please let me know what i am missing to chieve accessing the constant `PI` declared in `constants.js`

Comment: _"in other words, i can not have access to `PI`"_... not having intellisense for `PI` doesn't mean you can't use it. If you want VSCode to suggest it, you'll need a `.d.ts` file for the `constants` module

Comment: @Philisonstrike what is .d.ts please?

Comment: [About "*.d.ts" in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21247316/283366)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode uses Typescript type information in order to provide intellisense like auto-completion and argument hints.

You can create your own [module type descriptor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html) for the `constants` JavaScript module. Add a new `constants.d.ts` file along-side `constants.js` with the following contents

```ts
export declare const PI: number;
```

---

You can see the results in the below CodeSandbox example

[image: Edit ecstatic-lovelace-c8q5p2]

Without the `.d.ts` descriptor, the editor does not know about `constants.PI`

[image: no type hints]

But as soon as the descriptor is enabled, you get auto-completion and type hints

[image: with type hints]

Note that in either case, the code compiles and displays the correct value.

Comment: but i would like to use the same style as mentioned in constants.js please.should i just rename it from constants.js to constants.d.ts?

Comment: You don't need to change anything about your current code. The `constants.d.ts` is a **new** file

Comment: sorry but i would like to use the same notation mentioned in constants.js?!!

Comment: I really don't know what you're asking at this stage. There is absolutely nothing stopping you using `constants.PI` in your current code. VSCode won't give you any auto-completion but your code will compile and work correctly. If you _do_ want intellisense, all you have to do is create this one new `constants.d.ts` file with the content from my answer and VSCode **will** give you the auto-completion you're after

Comment: can the file titled .d.ts as the one you provided, contains the code mentioned in constants.js posted in my question?so sorry for the lake of understanding

Comment: No. It's just a type descriptor file. It has no runnable code

Comment: ok, then the file wit ext .d.ts is not relevant anyhow to the constants.js?if yes, then i can use either of the them..right?

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me again. The `.d.ts` file is literally only providing information for your editor (VSCode) to use.

Comment: :) i got you..but then what is the purpose or the need of constants.js if i am gonna use the one with ext .d.ts please

Comment: _"i got you"_... no, I don't think you do. `constants.js` has runnable, usable code; it is your **implementation**. `constants.d.ts` is just a descriptor file that describes the types pertaining to `constants.js` so your editor works nicer.

Comment: sure.and that mean, constants.d.ts can not use the notation of constants.js..right?

Comment: @LetsamrIt there may be tools that can generate `.d.ts` files from `.js` files but in this case, I'd be surprised if they worked correctly.